# How can i calculate $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty} n(\sqrt{3n^2+1}-\sqrt{3n^2})$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

How can i calculate this limit :
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n(\sqrt{3n^2+1}-\sqrt{3n^2})$$

I tried with the L'Hôpital rule and it's not working.

Comment: try 3rd binomical formula

Answer (score 6):

No need L'Hopital, let's look:

\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}n[\sqrt{3n^{2}+1}-\sqrt{3n^{2}}]&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n[(3n^{2}+1)-3n^{2}]}{\sqrt{3n^{2}+1}+\sqrt{3n^{2}}}\\
&=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3+\dfrac{1}{n^{2}}}+\sqrt{3}}\\
&=\dfrac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$\sqrt{3n^{2}+1}-\sqrt{3n^{2}} = \frac{\left(\sqrt{3n^{2}+1}-\sqrt{3n^{2}}\right)\left(\color{blue}{\sqrt{3n^{2}+1}+\sqrt{3n^{2}}}\right)}{\color{blue}{\sqrt{3n^{2}+1}+\sqrt{3n^{2}}}}=\frac{1}{\left(\sqrt{3n^{2}+1}+\sqrt{3n^{2}}\right)}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $\dfrac1n=h\implies h\to0^+$

$\sqrt{1+3n^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{h^2+3}}{\sqrt{h^2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{h^2+3}}h$ as $\sqrt{h^2}=|h|=+h$(here) as $h>0$

So, the problem reduces to $$\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{\sqrt{h^2+3}-\sqrt3}{h^2}$$

**Method**$\#1:$

Set $\sqrt{h^2+3}-\sqrt3=u$

**Method**$\#2:$
$$S=\lim_{h\to0^+}\dfrac{h^2+3-3}{h^2(\sqrt{h^2+3}+\sqrt3)}=?$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty} {n\cdot (3n^2+1-3n^2)\over (\sqrt{3n^2+1}+\sqrt{3n^2}) } = {1\over 2\sqrt{3}}$$

Answer (score 0):

write $$\frac{n(\sqrt{3n^2+1}-\sqrt{3n^2})(\sqrt{3n^2+1}+\sqrt{3n^2})}{\sqrt{3n^2+1}+\sqrt{3n^2}}=...$$

Answer (score 0):

Set $t=\frac{1}{n^2}$ then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n*(\sqrt{3n^2+1}-\sqrt{3n^2}) = \lim_{t \to0}\frac{ \sqrt{3+t}-\sqrt{3}}{t} =(\sqrt{3+t})'|_{t=0} =\color{red}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}}}$$